# Creating a Zip File System Provider in Java

Tags: java, filesystems

From [offical docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html), I have this small program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class ZipFSPUser {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {

        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
        env.put("create", "true");

        URI uri = (new File(args[0])).toURI();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);

    }
}
```

I call it in the Mac terminal like

```
java -jar app.jar path/to/some/file.zip
```

But it says

> Path component should be '/'

So then I decided to write the path myself:

```
URI uri = URI.create("file://path/to/my/file.zip");
```

And now it says

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authority component present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the [URI syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16).

> ```
> URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
> hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
>               / path-absolute
>               / path-rootless
>               / path-empty
> ```

and

> When authority is present, the path must either be empty or begin with
> a slash ("/") character.  When authority is not present, the path
> cannot begin with two slash characters ("//").

You don't have an authority. You simply want an absolute path. Your scheme is also wrong. From the link you've posted, you actually want `jar:<url>` as described [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/jar) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html). So

```
URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/path/to/my/file.zip");
```